# Most efficient way to clear array of vectors

Tags: c++

I have a graph representation which looks like this

```
vector<int> Graph[MAXN]
```

Next, I want to remove all previously set vectors. What is the fastest way to do it ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: You can't remove elements from an array.

Comment: Maybe not remove, but to clear all vectors

Comment: Define "remove"? Given the declaration, and assuming you want to empty all the vectors, the _best_ way would be to loop over all `MAXN` entries in `Graph` calling [`std::vector::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) on each. This will leave every `std::vector<int>` in `Graph` with no elements.

Comment: What way are you using now?

Comment: iteration over all elements and call clear method

Comment: That sounds like the only option you have anyway.

Comment: Given your current declaration, that's the best you can do.

Comment: Okay, one more question. Is using vector<vector<int>> V; and then calling V.clear() more efficient than iteration over Grap[] and calling .clear on each vector ?

Comment: If there's a difference, it's probably negligible.

Comment: `V.clear()` does a little more than calling `.clear()` on each vector. It deletes each vector entirely.

Comment: std::for_each(Graph, Graph+SIZE, [](vector<int> & v){v.clear(); }); // You might like this form of code.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real question of "efficiency" here. You must iterate through your array, and you must invoke `std::vector<int>::clear()` on each element of that array. So, just *do it*:

```
for (auto& v : Graph) {
   v.clear();
}
```